# Textool 1.5 crash in install in Blender 4.0.1

Tags: add-on

[image]

I have downloaded and install Blender 4.0.1 on my new computer. When I try to install (or really activate) TexTools it failed with following dump.

Does anyone know what's ongoing here? Seems to be a problem with import "Facemap".

In my last 3 version (3.6.0) all works fine.

Comment: Probably the same as https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304948/blender-4-0-crashes-when-opening-home-builder-products-build-decorations-materia

Answer (score 2):

The original [Textools by renderhjs](https://bitbucket.org/renderhjs/textools-blender/) was last updated for Blender 2.79.
SavMartin [forked it](https://github.com/SavMartin/TexTools-Blender) to update it to Blender 2.80 and has been maintaining it since with the help of other people from the community.

Any time a new Blender version is released with breaking changes in its Python API([which is the case for 4.0](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/4.0/Python_API)), addons are likely to need an update to be able to work in that version.

SavMartin's TexTools [received updates in the past days since 4.0's release](https://github.com/SavMartin/TexTools-Blender/commits/master), so you maybe you can already download the updated repository and install it, it might already work as is. Or wait for them to post a new official release. If the current repository doesn't solve your bug, you can report it in the Issues page.

Comment: can confirm the latest update fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Master branch was suggested on github and it worked for me on 4.0.1
https://github.com/SavMartin/TexTools-Blender/archive/refs/heads/master.zip
berfore that I was using 1.5 release which broke on Blender 4.0